# Heap Memory for a String in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, heap-memory

I have created a project file and in int main, I make a call to a function. In the function, there is a character array, corr[40], which stores the user's input letter by letter.(its a hangman game).After the function is executed, and then the program goes back to main. If the function is called again, then the array has the inputs of the previous call and is not erased. And hence only a few characters of the previous input are overwritten by new ones.

So I want to know how to allocate memory from heap to the array(using a pointer)? Or is there any other way I can correct this issue?

Comment: just use std::string. Especially it's a member of a class.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. If you want the array cleared when the function is called, you need to do it yourself. If you want to keep the data between calls, make it a parameter for the function.

Comment: how do I clear the array? for example if the first input is "CLEAR" and in the second input, if the letter S,F are entered of "FUSS", then the in the array it is "FLSSR"

Comment: @concept3d can you tell me the syntax for the same?

Comment: Show some code. It's always better to show code than to describe it.

Comment: @GhanashyamBC am not sure what do you mean by the syntax. just #include <string> and define a member variable `std::string name; // for example` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Did you try `memset` -ing the array to 0?

Comment: Please post a cut down code example - at the very least show how your class/function and array are declared

Comment: You clear the array by assigning whatever value you use to indicate emptiness to each of its elements. And "the heap" will not help you in any way.

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram it is not a constant array so its not allowing me to use memset

Comment: @Angew the point about the code is that its partly done by me and partly by my friend so i am not really sure on how it works. actually its a global variable and it is initially initialized by copying letter by letter from another array.and then there are a few cout statements

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `char[40]` as a local variable in a function. Since that's not a class type, there is no constructor. The initial values will depend on whatever used to be in that memory location before. That might very well be all or some of the previous letters.

If you want the array to be zero each time, you can just use `std::fill(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo), 0);`

Note that using heap memory is no solution. There's still no constructor to initialize the heap memory, so that too would have any old value. Using std::string, which *does* have a constructor, is a solution.

Comment: so I just add std::fill(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo), 0); in my code? when the function is called?

Comment: Right after the definition of the array. (And just to be clear, `foo` should be replaced with the name of your array, and you might need a header)

Comment: char corr[40];
std::fill(std::begin(corr),std::end(corr),0);

I get an error saying {expected constructor,destructor or type conversion before '(' token}